# Meaning of "an away"

Tags: meaning

There is a film called "plasticized"(http://www.plasticizedthemovie.com/about-the-film/).
And one researcher on the sailing voyage explains as below..

The philosophy that there is, **an away**, that, you know, we say we throw something away. 
That you can create something to be used for a minute that lasts forever,
is evil in my opinion. 
What I think needs to happen with people who, companies that produce plastic is in the whole scope of the products impact, they need to calculate for its environmental impact economically.

What does it mean "an away"(as noun?!)in these contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The philosophy that there is, **an away**, that, you know, we say we throw something away.

What he means is that we treat our world as if it were divided into two compartments: one is "**here**", where we enjoy things, and the other is "**away**", where unnecessary things could be dumped and forgotten.

But these things - plastic disposable items, for instance, made to be used only a short moment - are not going anythere, they remain on our planet.

He basically takes the phrase "to throw something away" and disassembles it, turning "away" into a noun in order to stress the absurdness of this consumerist perception of reality.

Answer (score 1):

The theory the speaker is putting forward is that when people say 'we throw something away' they think there is somewhere called *away* where the rubbish goes (and that this is a bad thing, and that plastic does not degrade, but goes on causing problems for ever...)

The argument may have something to recopmmend it, but not from a grammatical point of view: it's just an attempt to make a point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would say that 'an away' in my opinion, stands for *a product/thing that is used only once*, like a plastic bag but *for which it takes many years to biodegrade* and, thus, it harms nature.